# Copy pasting picture in Eclipse - R error

Tags: android

When I copy paste an image in the `drawable-hdpi` folder of my Android app in Eclipse, I get an error signaling there is something wrong with every activity class.
The error concerns `.R`
I already copy pasted another image before but it worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: image name should not contain special character and uppercase letters

Comment: and no spaces, and not begin with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when eclipse cant generate the R file, due to some error in the res folder.

Check your image name, that is probably the culprit, it should be named like this: "my_image_file.png". Only alphanumeric characters and the underscore are allowed.

Comment: yup that worked, tried changing the format before but it was the name in fact. Thanks for the help and sorry for the rookie question !

Answer (score 0):

just use only small latter with image name and don't use  like this    imageOne.jpg ,  imagetwo-hello.jpg

just use .png file

must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

hope it will help you